# problem with aequilibrae v.06.1 for QGIS

Tags: qgis

[image]

where to find binaries.ZIP file,whenever i click download,there is nothing,and also I can not download it from the website the picture gives[image]

when i use the version 1.0.1,there is often the third problem just as the picture shows,[image],and from the website https://aequilibrae.com/qgis/latest/getting_started/getting_started.html#getting-started,it seems the author also met this problem but he do not give how to solve the third problem????